# Consume WCF library with Windows Credential

Tags: c#, wcf, powershell

I've a WCF library and I want to switch from Anonymous to Windows Authentication. Settings in IIS and `Web.config` file seem to be fine, I can connect from powershell using `New-WebServiceProxy` but I have problem with C# client.

In powershell I needed to switch from this piece of code

```
New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri;
```

to this one

```
New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential;
```

In C# I referenced my library but how can I tell the client to "use default credentials"? I always get this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.